# Subscribed to 'assigned to (new) notification but not getting notifications

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

In MS DevOps I have enabled a subscription to send notices to the new user when a work item is newly assigned to them.  It doesn't send me notifications when I assign work items to myself.  I can enable to send to my specific email and it works.  So I think I have the permissions to do it.  Can anyone tell me if that functionality is working for them and what they did not make it work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We cannot tell you if what you do make sense if you don't show what you have done and which issues you get. Please edit your question to add more details , code and errors.

Comment: @Ray Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your email filtering service first, our email filtering service was filtering out some of the azure devops emails such as the standard notifications in most cases. @ mentions were coming from a different origin which were getting through.

If there is no problem with the mailbox filtering service, you can enable the following default subscription in the **Global notifications** of the Organization Settings.

[image]